# Facebook getAuthResponse error: OAuth2 support disabled

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

I am attempting to use the Facebook getAuthResponse() function and it is returning the following error:

```
function () {if(!FB._oauth)throw new Error('getAuthResponse called when OAuth2 support is '+'disabled.  Please fix.');return FB._authResponse;}
```

I am using the following for my initial Facebook Auth:

```
FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
            status: true, 
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
                  });
```

And the following code to load the JavaScript SDK:

```
 (function() {
               var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
               e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
               document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
                         }());

             google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
             google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', initialize);
```

If anyone could shed any light on what's going on here I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember this was a setting in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/XXXX/advanced page. Have you checked that?